# Pgrouting functions and geoms type not found

Tags: gis, postgresql-9.1, postgis, pgrouting

I have installed a `postgresql 9.1` and `postgis 2.0` from source.
Now I compiled and installed `pgrouting 2.0` (after one hour searching the dependencies).
I created the `extension` on my database in `postgres`.

I included the function from the sql files `pgrouting.sql`
But the functions I need are in `pgrouting_legacy.sql` and `pgrouting_dd_legacy.sql`

The error output is : `psql:/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/contrib/pgrouting-2.0/pgrouting_legacy.sql:299: ERROR:  type "geoms" does not exist`

Postgresql and Postgis are working fine...

I followed this documentation : 
http://pgrouting.org/docs/1.x/install.html

http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=pgrouting_osm2po_1

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be following the installation instructions for pgRouting 2.0 instead of the old 1.x which you linked above. See here: http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/installation/build.html#build

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was my fault. I installed it succefully but I tried to launch some functions that are no more in pgRouting 2.0 so I thought the installation failed.